# Property of the convex function defined over $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convex-analysis

Working on an analysis problem, I came to a result in the convex analysis which can help me. I couldn't prove that, and I tried to picture the intuition, but I did not make progress. The theorem is:

$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a $C^2$ strictly convex function with the following properties:

1.$f'(0)=0$

2.$\int_{0}^{1} f dy=0$.

The result is that $f(1)>0$ and $\int_{0}^{1} f^2 dy \leq \frac{1}{3} f(1)^2$.

Do you know any references that can help me with this theorem. I tried too many times but I do not have any picture in my mind.

Comment: The function $f=0$ satisfies the conditions but $f(1) = 0$, so this cannot be true without extra conditions.

Comment: @copper.hat: $f=0$ is not *strictly* convex.

Comment: @MartinR Seems to be an evolving question.

Comment: If $f(1) \le 0$ then you would have $f(x) \le 0$ and then $\int f =0$ would imply $f=0$.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

Because $f$ is convex (strictly convex, I assume), its second derivative is strictly positive and so its first derivative is increasing. Since $f’(0)=0$, the derivative must be positive on $(0,1]$. So you have an upward sloping curve.

To see why $f(1)$ must be positive, use the fact that the curve is upward-sloping. This fact entails that $f(x) < f(1)$ for all $x\in (0, 1)$, so if $f(1)$ were negative, the entirety of the curve would lie below the x-axis. But since $\int_0^1 f dy = 0$, it is not possible that all of the curve lies below the x-axis. Hence, we know that $f(1) > 0$.

Hopefully this helps you picture what is going on. Can you figure out the second inequality?

Comment: thank you. How it would be possible when  $\int_{0}^{1}f dy=0$

Comment: I am sorry, I get that what do you mean. I do not know how can I get the final inequality though.